# Building a webservice with mvc

Tags: php, mvc, web-services

I'am planning my website over here based on MVC.

And I am thinking about a webservice (who knows, maybe one day I'll create an android app or something).

The site and the webservice will behave diferently from each other.

So what should I do? Write different controllers for each... or stuff IFs all over the place?

For example: on the site, the controller will act as such:
Password correct?
---->redirect user to welcome screen
Password incorrect?
---->render login page again

But the webservice will simple show a json like:
{message: 'wrong password/sucess'}

Which one you think is the best approach?

Comment: Seperate the controllers, this is the way I use. That makes things easier when you have larger operations.

Comment: +1. Separate controllers for API and NON-API calls. API Controllers will be a lot ligher in general without the view rendering part (unless you count returning data as .json as a view).

Comment: yes edvinas.me, it is exactly what I was thinking, returning the json as a view. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "stuff IFs all over the place?" question sort of answers itself.  That's obviously not a good design.

You should separate the controllers, but have them rely on a common code base for shared actions.  For example, you should only have one place in your code that verifies a password.  Each controller should call this code and then respond with the appropriate behavior based on the context of that controller.